# Get (year,month) for the last X months

Tags: python, datetime

I got a very simple thing to to in python:
I need a list of tuples `(year,month)` for the last x months starting (and including) from today. So, for x=10 and today(July 2011), the command should output:

```
[(2011, 7), (2011, 6), (2011, 5), (2011, 4), (2011, 3), 
(2011, 2), (2011, 1), (2010, 12), (2010, 11), (2010, 10)]
```

Only the default datetime implementation of python should be used. I came up with the following solution:

```
import datetime
[(d.year, d.month) for d in [datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(weeks=4*i) for i in range(0,10)]]
```

This solution outputs the correct solution for my test cases but I'm not comfortable with this solution: It assumes that a month has four weeks and this is simply not true. I could replace the `weeks=4` with `days=30` which would make a better solution but it is still not correct.

The other solution which came to my mind is to use simple maths and subtract 1 from a months counter and if the month-counter is 0, subtract 1 from a year counter. The problem with this solution: It requires more code and isn't very readable either.

So how can this be done correctly?

Comment: Just fyi, `weeks=4` and `days=30` both fail if you run this code on, say, July 31.

Comment: thanks, thats the easiest border-case where my code does not work. You could make it work for those if you use `days=31`, but it is still not correct.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see it documented anywhere, but `time.mktime` will "roll over" into the correct year when given out-of-range, including negative, month values:

```
x = 10
now = time.localtime()
print([time.localtime(time.mktime((now.tm_year, now.tm_mon - n, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)))[:2] for n in range(x)])
```

Comment: J.F. Sebastian: Fixed.

Answer (score 8):

Using `relativedelta` ...

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_last_months(start_date, months):
    for i in range(months):
        yield (start_date.year,start_date.month)
        start_date += relativedelta(months = -1)

>>> X = 10       
>>> [i for i in get_last_months(datetime.datetime.today(), X)]
>>> [(2013, 2), (2013, 1), (2012, 12), (2012, 11), (2012, 10), (2012, 9), (2012, 8), (2012, 7), (2012, 6), (2012, 5)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Neatest would be to use [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division#Division_of_integers) (`//`) and [modulus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) (`%`) functions, representing the month by the number of months since year 0:

```
months = year * 12 + month - 1 # Months since year 0 minus 1
tuples = [((months - i) // 12, (months - i) % 12 + 1) for i in range(10)]
```

The `- 1` in the `months` expression is required to get the correct answer when we add 1 to the result of the modulus function later to get 1-indexing (i.e. months go from 1 to 12 rather than 0 to 11).

Or you might want to create a generator:

```
def year_month_tuples(year, month):
    months = year * 12 + month - 1 # -1 to reflect 1-indexing
    while True:
        yield (months // 12, months % 12 + 1) # +1 to reflect 1-indexing
        months -= 1 # next time we want the previous month
```

Which could be used as:

```
>>> tuples = year_month_tuples(2011, 7)
>>> [tuples.next() for i in range(10)]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**: Adding a `timedelta` version anyway, as it looks prettier :)

```
def get_years_months(start_date, months):
    for i in range(months):
        yield (start_date.year, start_date.month)
        start_date -= datetime.timedelta(days=calendar.monthrange(start_date.year, start_date.month)[1])
```

You don't need to work with `timedelta` since you only need year and month, which is fixed.

```
def get_years_months(my_date, num_months):
    cur_month = my_date.month
    cur_year = my_date.year

    result = []
    for i in range(num_months):
        if cur_month == 0:
            cur_month = 12
            cur_year -= 1
        result.append((cur_year, cur_month))
        cur_month -= 1

    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import datetime
    result = get_years_months(datetime.date.today(), 10)
    print result
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a function to do the date maths, it gets almost as nice as your original implementation:

```
def next_month(this_year, this_month):
  if this_month == 0: 
    return (this_year - 1, 12)
  else:
    return (this_year, this_month - 1)

this_month = datetime.date.today().month()
this_year = datetime.date.today().year()
for m in range(0, 10):
  yield (this_year, this_month)
  this_year, this_month = next_month(this_year, this_month)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do it without datetime libraries, you can convert to months since year 0 and then convert back

```
end_year = 2014
end_month = 5
start_year = 2013
start_month = 7

print list = [(a/12,a % 12+1) for a in range(12*end_year+end_month-1,12*start_year+start_month-2,-1)]
```

python 3 (`//` instead of `/`):

```
list = [(a//12,a % 12+1) for a in range(12*end_year+end_month-1,12*start_year+start_month-2,-1)]
print(list)
```

> > > [(2014, 5),
> > >        (2014, 4),
> > >        (2014, 3),
> > >        (2014, 2),
> > >        (2014, 1),
> > >        (2013, 12),
> > >        (2013, 11),
> > >        (2013, 10),
> > >        (2013, 9),
> > >        (2013, 8),
> > >        (2013, 7)]

Answer (score 0):

Or you can define a function to get the last month, and then print the months (
it's a bit rudimentary)

```
def last_month(year_month):#format YYYY-MM
    aux = year_month.split('-')
    m = int(aux[1])
    y = int(aux[0])

    if m-1 == 0:
        return str(y-1)+"-12"
    else:
        return str(y)+"-"+str(m-1)

def print_last_month(ran, year_month= str(datetime.datetime.today().year)+'-'+str(datetime.datetime.today().month)):
    i = 1 
    if ran != 10:
        print( last_month(year_month) )
        print_last_month(i+1, year_month= last_month(year_month))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def list_last_year_month(self):
    last_day_of_prev_month = date.today()
    number_of_years = self.number_of_years
    time_list = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for y in range(number_of_years+1):
        for m in range(13):
            last_day_of_prev_month = last_day_of_prev_month.replace(day=1) - timedelta(days=1)
            last_month = str(last_day_of_prev_month.month)
            last_year = str(last_day_of_prev_month.year)
            time_list[last_year].append(last_month)
    return time_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using datetime and relativedelta functions. This returns the past dates by subtracting the number of months(input). This function will return the full date and using the below functions it is possible to get the year and month separately.

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_past_date(number_of_months):
        return date.today() - relativedelta(months=number_of_months)
```

to get the year from the date

```
def get_year_from_the_date(date):
        return date.year
```

to get the month from the date

```
def get_month_from_the_date(date):
        return date.month
```