# timestamp from 3months ago

Tags: python, timestamp

I've a small script where I'm getting data from the last few months, based on the timestamp. Right now I'm using current day and a set date (currently May). Here's how I'm defining it:

```
today_time = int(time.mktime(date.today().timetuple())*1000000)
earlier_time = int(time.mktime(datetime.date(2011,05,01).timetuple())*1000000)
```

I'd like to change `earlier_time` from a set date (currently 2011,05,01) to, say, 90 days. I couldn't find how to do this, so your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Subtract 7776000 seconds from the current time?

Comment: Kinda related question ("N months ago", as opposed to "N * 30 days ago"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576187/get-year-month-for-the-last-x-months/6576603#6576603

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
then = now - datetime.timedelta(days=90)
```

Comment: After the above conversion, In order to convert the type(now) i.e. <datetime.datetime object> to 'timestamp', using time.mktime(now.timetuple()) worked just fine for me.